# Simple way to store a session id with Xamarin.Auth

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I would like to store my users' session ids using Xamarin.Auth to support cross-platform but can't find out how to write it or grab it when needed. I tried following [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/general/store-credentials/) but i dont get where they get half the methods.

Comment: `i dont get where they get half the methods.` Source code is available: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/General/StoreCredentials/

Comment: When I use 'Xamarin.Auth' it says it's not in the name space 'Xamarin' but if i check my NuGets under installed i have 'Xamarin.Auth 1.5.0.3' installed

Comment: Any help? bumpp